# Linux - Couldn't load MySql

Tags: phpmyadmin, lampp

I am extremely new to linux, i have setup a lampp server in my linux system, and i started lampp
but couldn't start MySql,i am getting the following command.

```
    Starting XAMPP for Linux 1.7.1...
XAMPP: Starting Apache with SSL (and PHP5)...
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...
XAMPP: Couldn't start MySQL!
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...
XAMPP for Linux started.
```

Please anyone help me!!!

Comment: Try looking in the log files - there should be a logs directory in the folder, there may be a log file in there or perhaps in the mysql directory.

Once you have the log message of the error, we can help you better :)

Comment: Thanks for reply, i have changed the permission to 777, then i got the message "Wrong permissions on configuration file, should not be world writable".

Comment: Try 555 or 111, both 555 is execute and read, 111 is execute only.

Answer (score 2):

My resolution, that worked for me:

http://adventux.blogspot.pt/2012/11/xampp-couldnt-start-mysql.html